# Fatal error: Call to a member function calculate() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\project1\dealer\admin\controller\sale\order.php on line 795

Tags: opencart, price

Am creating a custom total for products. Am using this code

```
$customerGroupId=$_COOKIE['customerGroupId'];

if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) 
{
    $priceOld = $newPrice;
    if($customerGroupId==25||$customerGroupId==0||$customerGroupId==26) 
    {
        $total1 = $this->getPriceListForGhee($product['name'], $priceOld, $product['types'], $product['quantity']);
    }
    else
    {
        $total1 = $this->getPriceList($product['name'], $priceOld, $product['types'], $product['quantity']);
    }
        $total=$this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($total1, $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
}
else
{
    $total = false;
}
```

But i got some error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function calculate() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\project1\dealer\admin\controller\sale\order.php on line 795

How can i solve this error...?

Comment: Did you load the **tax** model?

Comment: No am not sure can you assist me..?

Comment: but this code is working `$total=$this->currency->format($total1, $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));`

Comment: seems like **tax** exists only in front controller. Not the admin path.

Comment: Here am remove `calculate` function

Comment: This cause error: `$this->tax->calculate`. So `tax` does not exists. You have to look in controller other method `calculate` and make yours with those example

Comment: Thank you i will try @AlexSlipknot

Comment: `$taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();` this is the code right..?

Comment: Nope. This code will work only for users in store (not in the admin)

Comment: Yeah your right i tried this but it's not working

Comment: Can you tell me the code please...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for getting total for product in Admin path you can use this code to implement yours:

```
$total = $this->currency->format($product['total'], $currency_code, $currency_value);
```

Of course you have to specify your own `$currency_code` and `$currency_value`

Comment: `$total=$this->currency->format($total1, $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));` it is same right..?

Comment: not really the same. Because of different parameters